# Position absolute without parent height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

I would like to place 4 divs like the following picture; the parent div has unknown height (auto). Each div would have an image with 100% fit, then the height of the divs are also unknown.

I was thinking using absolute position on the divs, but I need the background of the parent.
Is there some jquery plugin or css3 trick to do the job?

[image]

Comment: Please provide the HTML + CSS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divHeight = $('.div1').height() + $('.div2').height();
    $('.containerDiv').css({ "height" : divHeight });
});
```

This will tally the heights of `.div1` and `.div2` (of course you can adjust to your liking) and apply that height to whatever your containing div, or whatever div you want.

Comment: Thanks, knowing the height of the divs I could "fool" the fluid positioning using absolutes